# HAProxy config file and reqirep

Tags: haproxy

I am going through an existing HAProxy config file and trying to make sense out of it. I am new to HAProxy. What does the following line do?

reqirep ^Host:\ 180.115.110.100 Host:\ www.foo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It replaces lines matching `Host: 180.115.110.100` with `Host: www.foo.com` in the HTTP header in a case insensitive way. See also [the documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt).

Comment: Thanks for that. When would this be done, when the request comes in or goes out? Also, any idea why would someone what to do something like this?

Comment: It is done only on request headers that come in and will be forwarded by haproxy. As to why someone would want that: some servers refuse requests containing a  `Host: XXX` headers where they don't recognize `XXX`. If the server cannot be fixed, an haproxy workaround may work.